# How to start slideshow

Tags: imac

I used the answers - how to start slideshow in Mac, but it does not work. I have iMac and may be somebody can help me. I open my pictures in the finder and then use one to start the slide show using the View and then  Slideshow.
Nothing work

Comment: Can you add a link to the instructions you've followed? Also, in which application do the pictures open? What exactly *does* happen if you select View->Slideshow?

Answer (score 2):

To be clearer - if you actually ***open*** *all* the relevant images *in* the Preview app, the slideshow option inside the Preview app will work.

If instead you *highlight* the files in Mac OS **Finder**, and *then* click Option+Spacebar, you will *Quick Look* these inside Finder, which will include a slideshow option as well - this is the far faster approach in most cases.

Here are two screengrabs of the Quick Look function in Finder: one showing per-image-view, the other a grid view.

Notice that in *both* cases I have all the files *highlighted* in Mac OS **Finder**, and *then* click the Quick View keyboard shortcut:

[image]
[image]

As you can see in the screengrab, if I want to, I then have the option to open any one of these images in the Preview app, should I want to adjust colour curves, print, annotate or other such tasks.

Comment: Both methods work, but both have their problems. Using quicklook, the images are not zoomed to full screen if they're small. Using Finder, they're zoomed, but look terribly pixelated. On the other hand, if you've set up your screensaver to run a slide show, the images look great. I wish there was a way to run a slide show that looks as good as the screensaver.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Option+Spacebar to open a Quick Look slideshow.

Alternatively you can open the image in Preview and use the slideshow function from there.